# Duplicate entry IInAppBillingService

Tags: android, duplicates

Recently I implemented app billing to my android app
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-service

Then I implemented "stickerpipe" and then I got this error
`Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class`

Should I remove IInAppBillingService.aidl the one that I added manually ??

I tried this `exclude group: 'com.android.vending.billing'` but no change.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class

this Error is because Duplicate Entry of IInAppBillingService class that is added by you in main package.
Check carefully if you have added it at another palace from where compiler is detecting.

```
Hint:  if you added this File manually and added in gradle dependencies also  like in my case.
than try to remove this from one place.
```

Hope any will gate helpfull.